# Is the database getting a hit from PLP i.e. category page?

Tags: java, indexing, solr, sap-commerce-cloud

From what I know the database should never be hit from the category page or PLP.

However, I have found a trail that is doing exactly that !

```
DefaultCategoryService#getCategoryForCode
CommerceCategoryFacetDisplayNameProvider.java:158
CommerceCategoryFacetDisplayNameProvider.java:87
SearchResponseBreadcrumbsPopulator.java:74
commerceSolrSearchResponseConverter
DefaultSolrProductSearchService
```

How is this even possible?
This is causing the error of missing categories.

Comment: Is it OOTB version?

Comment: @mkysoft yes. all these classes are OTB

Comment: I am sure all of them OOTB class. DefaultCategoryService#getCategoryForCode is using DAO object. Maybe you have also some customization to complate product data from db.

Comment: @mkysoft these are all OOTB classes. DefaultCategoryService#getCategoryForCode is calling db and yet the trail suggests that it is possible to hit this class from PLP. Why?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this part is about populating the breadcrumb text,
Solr does not store the category name in Solr by default, so it uses the database to fetch the category name of the current Locale to populate it, it's only one call per page load, so it does not affect the page loading performance, so it's normal if the category is indexed and missing from the database you will get errors